# How can I hide a modal element in Dittofi?

Tags: simplemodal

How do I use a "modal" element in #Dittofi. When I add the element it covers the entire page and I cannot access elements underneed.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the modal box, you need to select the box marked "Modal" in the breadcrumb trial at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Then you can select the modal settings box to either show or hide the modal box.

[image]

Let me know if that works for you?